# Member value lost when passing object by pointer

Tags: c, pointers, stack, freebsd

I am very new to the FreeBSD world and am currently porting my terminal emulation library from Linux to FreeBSD and Mac OS. I've encountered some very strange behavior such that when I pass a struct by pointer to a subroutine the member values become zeroed out.  This does not happen on Linux or Mac OS.  It also does not matter if the compiler is GCC or Clang.

I've confirmed that the member value is correct before the subroutine is called and the parent struct is passed by pointer.

I've tested the same code on Linux and Mac OS and they do not exhibit the problem.

I've switched between GCC and Clang on FreeBSD and that seems to have no effect.

I've consider that stack smashing *could* be happening but it seems unlikely because ulimit shows that the stack size on Linux is 8M but on FreeBSD it's much larger (524 MB).  I've also tried compiling with -fstack-protector-strong but none of this matters.

```
#include "vterm.h" 
#include "vterm_private"  // vterm_t and vterm_desc_t defined here

void vterm_cursor_move_backward(vterm_t* vterm) {
  vterm_desc_t* v_desc = NULL;
  int min_row;
  int idx;

  // idx = vterm_buffer_get_active(vterm);
  idx = 0;  // hard set to 0 just for debugging
  v_desc = &vterm->vterm_desc[idx];

  // printf() will display a value of zero
  printf("%d\n\r", v_desc->ccol);
  fflush(stdout);
}

void vterm_interpret_ctrl_char(vterm_t* vterm, const char* data) {
  vterm_desc_t *v_desc = NULL;
  int idx;
  char verb;

  // idx = vterm_buffer_get_active(vterm);
  idx = 0;  // hard set to 0 just for debugging
  v_desc = &vterm->vterm_desc[idx];

  verb = data[0];

  switch (verb) {
    case '\b': {
      // the following printf will print a positive number
      printf("%d\n\r", v_desc->ccol);
      fflush(stdout);
      vterm_cursor_move_backward(vterm);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the value of v_desc->ccol to be identical in both functions. [Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/dc9RZ2) [Github Link](https://github.com/TragicWarrior/libvterm) See files vterm_ctrl_char.c and vterm_cursor.c

Comment: Can you give us the definition of `vterm_t` and/or a link to the source code? I would like to try to compile the code in your question.

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running your code with Undefined Behavior (UB) Sanitizer (`-fsanitize=undefined`) or Address Sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer`)?

Comment: @cmwt, sure.  the project is at:

https://github.com/TragicWarrior/libvterm

and the branch is freebsd-bugfixes-2

The code snippets come from the files vterm_ctrl_char.c and vterm_cursor.c

Comment: @cmwt, I have tried -fsanitize=address but I have not tried the others.  I will do that now.

Comment: @cmwt, when you build the project a demo program will be generated called "vshell".  when you hit the backspace key it should be have as expected.  however, due to the bug, the conditional which evaluates the current column (ccol) behaves wrongly.

Comment: @cmwt -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer had no effect.

Comment: @cmwt, also -fsanitize=undefined made no perceptible difference.

Comment: @Bryan_Christ, is `vterm_interpret_ctrl_char()` supposed to have a declaration/definition for `v_desc` e.g. `vterm_desc_t* v_desc = NULL;`?

Comment: @cmwt, yes.  ```v_desc``` is initially set to NULL but you'll see that just a few lines down it is set as ```v_desc = &vterm->vterm_desc[idx];```

Comment: @Bryan_Christ, but  `vterm_interpret_ctrl_char()` doesn't  have a declaration for `v_desc` only `vterm_cursor_move_backward()` does.

Answer (score 0):

After countless hours of debugging I figured out that data in the `vterm_desc_t` structure was actually being shifted causing the member value to be set to zero.  Although, the ncurses header file is included via `vterm_private.h`, on FreeBSD that doesn't seem to matter.  Both GCC and Clang are happy to silently compile the `vterm_cursor.c` translation unit with bad / incomplete alignment.

I would recommend anyone running into kind of problem to try and compile each translation unit individually which is how I unearthed it.  For example `gcc -S vterm_cursor.c`

Thank you to everyone who took a look at this.